# How to add simple authentication to azure mobile/web apps with Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services

My goal is to secure my mobile app custom API methods and use then via httpclient(c#).

As a part of the testing I used Postman to request a token and use it to access the resource.

Comment: Please note that even self-answered questions should meet the site's quality requirements; see [ask]. *"How to"* questions aren't a good for for SO, consider writing this up on a blog or something.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will make a note of it.

Answer (score 2):

I will explain with the vanilla template that comes when creating a new Mobile App.

1. Create a new mobile app.
2. Publish it to Azure.
3. Open it on Azure portal, Go to **Settings** blade. Find **Authentication / Authorization**.
4. Turn **App Service Authentication to On** and select **Azure Active Directory>Express>Create a new AD app**.
5. Open Active Directory (Management Portal), pick the directory for your account.
6. Select Applications, the one you just created.
7. Go to Configure tab and copy the **ClientId, Create a Key**, copy it too.
8. Click on **View EndPoints** at the bottom and copy the **OAuth 2.0 Token EndpointOauth2.0 Token**
9. Now open the mobile app project and decorate the controller/method you want to project with [Authorize].

You should be all set with the setup.

Now open your favorite client, in my case Postman and

Step 1: Request a token

```
Method: POST
URL : {Oauth TokenEndPoint from Step. 8}
grant_type : client_credentials
client_id : {one copied from AD section in Step. 7}
client_secret : {one copied from AD section in Step. 7}
resource : {one copied from AD section in Step. 7}
```

You will receive a response like this

```
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "expires_on": "1453151213",
  "not_before": "1453147313",
  "resource": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
  "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Now copy the access_token and use it in your request to the mobile app.

```
   Method: Get
    URL : https://MyMobileApp.azurewebsites.net/api/values?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0
   Headers : Authorization : Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

In case if you run into any issues, here is a key step. Go to Azure portal and **turn on Application Logging, Detailed error messages, Failed request tracking under Diagnostics logs** (Settings blade).

Now you can see whats happening and much more detailed logging under **Log Stream(Tools blade)**.